# how do I give the TLS1.2 parameter in the Oracle jdbc thin connection url

Tags: oracle, jdbc, driver, tls1.2, thin

I would like to use the TLS1.2 while connecting to database.
I am using odbc8.jar
My current url is of the format: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/servicename`

I am not having an oracle installed and I dont have the tnsnames.ora I just have the thin client. So I am not able to use this

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=IP)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=testdb)))

I am looking to add TLS1.2 to the shorter url above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What is the JDBC driver that you are using? Check out the [SSL blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets#TLSv1.2) for more details